# interaction of ccfonts and enumitem packages

Tags: enumitem

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{ccfonts}

% \usepackage{enumitem}
% \setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\Large\arabic*}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\Large\arabic{enumi}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item an item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

with `\usepackage{ccfonts}` commented or not, everything is fine, but with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ccfonts}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\Large\arabic*}

%\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\Large\arabic{enumi}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item an item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I get

```
 Illegal parameter number in definition of \enit@a.
```

If I delete `\Large` or comment `\usepackage{ccfonts}`, everything runs smoothly.

Any help in understanding this behaviour is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply move the `\Large` to its correct position.

[image: item]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ccfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*,font=\Large}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item an item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```